# Prevent iOS autofocus on first visible input

Tags: javascript, html, webkit

It drives me crazy, but if I have an  visible, iOS always autofocuses on it and shows the keyboard. I tried setting tabindex = -1 but was unsuccessful.

Answer (score 1):

I meet the same issue with you and fixed by this way:
Add a readonly text field at the beginning of the form

```html
<input type="tel" size="5" tabindex="-1" readonly
                   style="position:fixed;-webkit-appearance：none;box-shadow:none;border:none;background:none;cursor:default;" />
```